# Enforce Java File needs admin permissions

Tags: java, file, permissions

I have a question about checking file permissions in Java.

I am accessing a file, and for security reasons I want it to be in a location that requires admin permissions.

I can see how to check a File using isWritable, which checks if *I* can write to it (I have admin permissions)  but I want to know that others who do not have admin permissions can NOT write to it.

Something like file.getOwner().isAdmin()

Comment: Have you considered that you would also have to run your app using admin permissions? This means the user starting it needs to be able to elevate the permissions, and that's the way this user could also use to read the file itself

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the concept of file ownership isn't modelled in the Java filesystem APIs

Comment: I suppose that in itself answers my question!